# responsive time scale for different time ranges

Tags: javascript, d3.js

For a variable date extent, i want to implement an adapting x axis, that also adjusts to an available window width. I got some working code that determines the extent width and changes the axis tick format function. Also it adjusts the number of ticks depending on the extent width.

```js
if (range <= 1000*60*60) {
    axis.ticks(d3.time.minute, step)
        .tickFormat(d3.time.format('%M:%S'));
} else if (range <= 1000*60*60*24) {
    axis.ticks(d3.time.hour, step)
        .tickFormat(d3.time.format('%H:%M'));
} else if (range <= 1000*60*60*24*7) {
    axis.ticks(d3.time.day, step)
        .tickFormat(d3.time.format('%d.%m'));
} else if (range <= 1000*60*60*24*7*30) {
    axis.ticks(d3.time.week, step)
        .tickFormat(d3.time.format('%d.%m'));
} else {
    axis.ticks(d3.time.month, step)
        .tickFormat(d3.time.format('%d.%m.%Y'));
}
```

`step` is the result of a linear scale:

```js
function getSteps(width) {
    var scale = d3.scale.linear()
        .domain([0, 1200])
        .range([14, 1]);

    return Math.ceil(scale(width));
}
```

The code does work i a way, but it feels like a dirty hack and the result is somehow unpredictable. I put a sample on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/risto/euyavq4n/4/) where the extent spans 24 hours, starting at the current time. When resizing the jsfiddle result view, you'll notive that the axis always shows a midnight tick, that is not evenly distributed.

So, is there be better/cleaner/more reliable way of doing this?

Comment: D3 adjusts time scales automatically already. If you want to change the default behaviour, changing the existing implementation is probably the best approach.

Comment: The default behavior doesn't satisfy my requirements, e.g. overlapping of labels, reduces tick size depending on the svg width, etc.. How do you change the "existing implementation"?

Comment: You take the existing code and modify it.